# Outlook 2000 email table formatting

Tags: outlook, html-table, formatting, html-email

In my email I have a html table. Table width is set to 900px. 
I need to support initial text format set by user (only line breaks). So after a lot of tests I found out that for Outlook 2007 the best solution was tag `<Pre>`. I wrap text with this tag. But the problem is that some lines are very long and don't have breaks. In this case all email clients automatically breaks lines so table width is not changed. But Outlook 2000-2003 displays this lines without wrapping them. So the table width is increasing.
How this can be fixed? If I remove `<pre>`
 tag everything is ok, long lines are autowrapped, table width is 900px but in this case I loose user text format (line breaks set by user).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the width of your email should not be larger than 600px. I recommend looking into using a framework or boilerplate template. This will make your life a hell of a lot easier. I personally like [Zurb's Ink framework](http://www.zurb.com/ink), but certainly there are others out there that will work just as well.

Good luck.